# Print and sum each element in a array in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have the array `list=[1, 2, 3, 4]`

How do I get the following output?

```
1+2+3+4 = 10
```

I know I could use sum(list), but I need each item on the array printed with "+"

Comment: Post the code that you have tried. You should be able to use a loop to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most pythonic solution I can think of; Use string formatting instead of the `+` operator when using strings - it's more efficient and a good habit to get into, use `map` to remap the integers to strings and `str.join` to efficiently create the question string.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print('{} = {}'.format('+'.join(map(str, numbers)), sum(numbers)))
```

Comment: `(str(number) for number in numbers)` might be replaced by `map(str, numbers)`

Answer (score -1):

```
print('+'.join(mylist) + ' = ' + str(sum(mylist)))
```

This should work for you

Comment: This gives the error `expected str instance, int found`, because `str.join` cannot be used on a list of  `int`s

Comment: Answering "do my homework for me" questions doesn't help anyone but the student (and then only briefly).  Also, code-only answers are generally not helpful (especially when they don't work due to a `TypeError`) --- you should explain what your code does and why.